# update statement based end date of previous row equaling start date of next row

Tags: sql, sap-iq

I have identified overlapping dates from trainers that trained users between a start date and end date. I now need to identify those USER_IDs where the end date for one of their trainers is the same as the start date for their next trainer. I need to flag them 'Y' and 'N'.

I run into a problem when there are trainers who have the same start date and end date as the prior trainers end date for the USER_ID.

```
UPDATE #SERVICE A
SET DIS_ADM_MATCH = CASE WHEN B.FROM_DATE = A.TO_DATE OR
                              A.FROM_DATE  = B.TO_DATE
                         THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
FROM #SERVICE A
INNER JOIN #SERVICE B
ON A.USER_ID = B.USER_ID
AND A.TRAINER_ID <> B.TRAINER_ID;
```

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
update service
    set DIS_ADM_MATCH = (case when exists (select 1
                                           from service s2
                                           where s2.user_id = service.user_id and
                                                 s2.from_date = service.to_date
                                          )
                              then 'Y' else 'N'
                         end);
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, unfortunately I am unable to use a subquery inside a conditional expression as it is not supported.

Comment: @Leigh.Granger . . . I do not recall a limitation like that in Sybase IQ.  Are you sure that is the real problem?  (I fixed an issue with table aliases.)